# 27 points median filter

Tags: fpga, filter, verilog

Edit:

I successfully made it work, but the algorithm not efficient
I taking the date coming in to my block, pipeline the data for how much points I need to median filter (for example 31), take all the 31 pipeline points and send to sorting algorithm block which returns bus with the sorted data, from this bus I taking only the median value (middle of the bus) and output it.

[image]

The only hard thing in this block diagram I sketched is the sorting algorithm, right?
So I found verilog code in GitHub for bitonic sort:
https://github.com/mcjtag/bitonic_sorter

connected it to the rest of my block, and everything cool I getting the sorting right and successfully calculating the median value every clock cycle.
This approach working but because this much of comparators every clock cycle I'm overloading my FPGA with complexity and a lot of LUTs (I sorting 31 points every clock cycle.. that ALOT).

How you guys think I should make this median filter algorithm better? sorting the whole array every clock cycle seems like solution but naive one.

Comment: The pdf is for a 2D filter processing images and not a 1D filter processing a signal - why don't you search for a more appropriate FIR low-pass filter solution aimed at FPGAs?

Comment: You need to show us your code for the 9-point filter, and also the code for your attempt to extend it to 27 points. Explain exactly how the implementation failed, including the full text of any error messages.

Comment: Why a median filter? why not just a FIR, why not a moving average filter. pick the filter for what you are trying to clean up

Comment: @BrianDrummond
Can you guys who suggest using FIR filter, give me direction how to calculate the coefficients for Median Filter?

Comment: Hey, guys! A median filter is NOT a linear filter, so FIR techniques are not helpful.

Comment: As you are aware, computing a median requires sorting the data. The paper you referenced is sorting image data, and requires that a result must be produced on every clock cycle, which means that a systolic sorting array is required. It sounds like your application would not require a result every clock, which means that you have the flexibility to use multiple clock cycles to do the sorting, greatly reducing the logic resource requirements. If you can be more specific about your actual requirements, we can suggest appropriate approaches.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks, I was confused here. Deleting my comments.

Comment: @DaveTweed I dont think its that matter if this image or just vector, because 3x3 window can be converted to 9 objects array (and this how I did the factor 9 median filter using this paper).  My requirement is that Median Block delete unwanted peaks from the spectrum, Im applying this filter after the FFT block, I do need the output data fast, I dont care if there will be a delay of clocks because of pipeline but I do need result every clock cycle after the initial delay.

Comment: Yes, but the logic complexity of a sorting array grows with the square of the number of items to be sorted. 3x the data is going to require 9x as much logic. As @ElliotAlderson said, you need to show us exactly what you tried.

Comment: @DaveTweed I edited the post with my attempt

Comment: You can't extend a median filter by attaching small median filters to its individual inputs. It simply doesn't work that way! You really need to build a new array that has 27 layers.

Comment: @DaveTweed i edited again the post with better attempt that returns the correct value 60% of the times, and when it fail it return value 2-5 away from the median.  it seems like I'm close to the right algorithm, but I doing something wrong in the way.

Comment: It's because, like Dave said, your comparator array isn't deep enough!

Comment: @DmitriS what do you mean by that? what can I do to make it deep enough? what more I should compare? Can I have some leads? thanks!

Comment: Looking at the paper, they've actually adopted an optimized FPGA sorting from a different source - it's cited source (8) in the end of the paper. If you have the computing power, simplest thing to do is to implement a scaled version of the basic sort, like in image 4, but you need a 27x27 number of nodes for that. Alternatively, of you need an optimal solution, search for systolic architecture technique papers that will show how to reduce the number of nodes needed to perform median filtering.

Comment: I've taken a closer look at your proposed method, and the reason it doesn't work is because you are discarding values too early - you grouped the inputs into 9 groups to find their medians, but your assumption here is wrong, since you aren't calculating an average: median(a,b,c,d,e,f...z) isn't the same as median(median(a,b,c), median(d,e,f), median(...z)).