# Median Filter FPGA

Tags: fpga, filter, verilog

I trying to build on my FPGA project median filter for 1-d vector,
I need my median filter to be large, the Internet is full with references for 9 points median filter but didn't saw anything for larger median filters.
For example I need median filter somewhere in the size range of 31-51 points.
My input data is 8-bit width data every clock cycle.

So the straight forward approach is to take the date coming in to my block, pipeline the data for how much points I need to median filter (for example 31), take all the 31 pipeline points and send to sorting algorithm block which returns bus with the sorted data, from this bus I taking only the median value (middle of the bus) and output it.

[image]

The only hard thing in this block diagram I sketched is the sorting algorithm, right?
So I found verilog code in GitHub for bitonic sort:
https://github.com/mcjtag/bitonic_sorter

connected it to the rest of my block, and everything cool I getting the sorting right and successfully calculating the median value every clock cycle.
This approach working but because this much of comparators every clock cycle I'm overloading my FPGA with complexity and a lot of LUTs (I sorting 31 points every clock cycle.. that ALOT).

How you guys think I should make this median filter algorithm better? sorting the whole array every clock cycle seems like solution but naive one.

Comment: How does your previous question differ? [27 points median filter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503657/27-points-median-filter)

Comment: @Andyaka here I provided already working algorithm (in the last question I asked why it didnt work and how to make it work -> you guys said my approach to the problem: take 9 point median and extend it wasnt right) . Here I have working median filter in length of 51 and 31, I just asking How could I make it better? Its to complex for the hardware to sort 31 points every clock cycle, what is better approach?

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: In your previous question you talked about how the solution you found was too complex and asked for more efficient methods. That is pretty much exactly what you are asking with this question.

Comment: ok Im closing and editing the last question.